# RichTextBox loses focus and caret position after modifying ListBox item

Tags: winforms, listbox, richtextbox, caret

I am trying to update Listbox Item text when modifying the RichTextBox, but the RTB keeps on losing focus, i even tried doing it in a BackgroundWorker, but still the same, here is my code:

```
    private void RTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBOX.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            if (!ListChangeBW.IsBusy)
            {
                ListChangeBW.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListChangeBW_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!InvokeRequired)
        {
            ListB.Items[ListB.SelectedIndex] = RTB.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ListB.Items[ListB.SelectedIndex] = RTB.Text;
            }));
        }
    }
```

I know the last part of my code doesn't match up because i send the arguments but i thought it would just confuse you, the changement does work, it's just that the RTB loses focus, and if i make it gain focus, the caret is in the last position of the text, is there anyway to make the changement background or in another thread ?

Comment: A BackgrondWorker is supposed to perform work in the background. You're using it to update an object in the foreground thread. From the wrong handler. You just need, in `RTB_TextChanged`:  `if (ListB.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
ListB.Items[ListB.SelectedIndex] = RTB.Text;`. This also won't cause your RTB to lose focus.

Comment: Your code is what pushed me to use a BackgroundWorker, it caused the same error, but, is there anyway to update in another thread ???

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use another thread to immediately push back the result to the foreground thread. And, no, that code doesn't cause the *problem* you mentioned. If your RTB loses the focus, something else is causing it. Check your code.